# How do I create a star-like fluorescent light emitting sphere in Eevee?

Tags: modeling, shaders

[image]

I am trying to replicate part of the image shown above. Specifically, I want to have a sphere that is fluorescing light. I am using emission, but I am trying to get a star-like light twinkle pattern as seen in the image. I am using Eevee to render. I appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could crete a sphere, give it an *Emission* shader (increase its *Strength* as much as needed), and in the *Compositor* use a *Glare* node to create the beams:

[image]